# Automatically refresh navbar when service data changes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, service, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to make a login-logout navbar, which only shows the logout button when there is a user logged in, and only shows the Login button when there isn't any user logged in. I'm using firebase auth service and one of its functions detects whether there is a user logged in or not. I'm achieving this by putting an *ngIf on each button I want it to check, like this:

```html
<a *ngIf="!_auth.userData" routerLink="/auth/login" class="login active">Login</a>
<a *ngIf="!_auth.userData" routerLink="/auth/register" class="register active">Register</a>
<a *ngIf="_auth.userData" routerLink="/landing" class="landing active">Landing</a>
<div class="divider anchor active">|</div>
<li class="profile anchor active">Profile</li>
<li class="paginator anchor active">Paginator</li>
<li class="search anchor active">Search</li>
<li class="ng-content anchor active">NgContent</li>
<li class="footer anchor active">Footer</li>
<div class="divider anchor active">|</div>
<a *ngIf="_auth.userData" (click)="_auth.SignOut()" class="logout active">Logout</a>
<a *ngIf="!_auth.userData" routerLink="/auth/forgot" class="forgot active">Forgot Password</a>
```

The actual login is inside the login component and has the next code:

```html
<button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" class="button" type="submit" (click)="_auth.SignIn(userEmail.value, userPassword.value)">Login</button>
```

The *ngIf detects the state of _auth.userData, this function returns null when no user is logged in.

```js
    /* Saving user data in localstorage when 
    logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this._afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', "");
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!);
      }
    })
  }
```

It works fine, but I have to refresh the page manually every time a login or logout in order for the navbar to refresh. How can I make it automatically refresh when the user logs in or logs out?

Comment: how do you set `_auth.userData` when the user logs in? What I would do, is to 1. add an observable to your authService, something like `isLoggedIn$ = BehaviorSubject(false)`, 2. change the value after login, eg. `isLoggedIn$.next(true)` 3. and then I'd observe for changes in that value in the component to detect if user is really logged in or not.

Comment: i added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your userData holds the current user value, and you cannot detect that change in your template. What I would do is:

```
// assuming it's an auth service, I'd do something like this: set the value of the login state in your public service property based on the localstorage value
isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(!!localStorage.getItem('user'));

// service call when logging in - change the state of the isLoggedIn$
this._afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.userData = user;
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || "{}");
    this.isLoggedIn$.next(true);
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || "{}");
    this.isLoggedIn$.next(false);
  }
})

// and in the template file
<a *ngIf="!(_auth.isLoggedIn$ | async)" routerLink="/auth/login" class="login active">Login</a>
<a *ngIf="_auth.isLoggedIn$ | async" routerLink="/auth/register" class="login active">register</a>
```

Comment: seems like it works, only issue now is it won't let me assign ! before the call, it gives me this error 

Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<unknown> | Subscribable<unknown> | Promise<unknown> | null 
| undefined'.

Comment: check this example for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqswmn